# how to set default value for select field inside a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In code i have:

```
<%= form_for(:category,:url=>{:action=>'update',:id=>@category.id}) do |f|%>
  <div class="field">
    <b style="color: #808080;"> Cuisine name:&nbsp;</b>
    <%= f.select :cuisine_id,options_from_collection_for_select(@cuisines,"id","cuisine_name"),prompt:'select cuisine'  %>
```

I am using this form to update "cuisine_name". The problem is that i want to set default value to this field.Now i am getting all values available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there.  from the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select):

```
options_from_collection_for_select(collection, value_method, text_method, selected = nil)
```

so you need to pass one more argument to create an option which is selected by default

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@cuisines,"id","cuisine_name", <your thing here>)
```

Comment: `<%= f.select :cuisine_id,options_from_collection_for_select(@cuisines,"id","cuisine_name",f.cuisine_id),prompt:'select cuisine'  %>` i am getting undefined method cuisine_id` error

Comment: glad it helped - what was your final working code?  it's nice to add that to your original question so people searching for this in the future have a working model to see :)